# Getting 'geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator is not present' even when element is on the page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spock, geb

In Geb based test I'm using very simple checking:

```
at ReportsPage
```

where page object contains:

```
static at = {
    $("#navContent .current").text() == "Reports"
}
```

This check works fine on one PC but fails with *'geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator is not present'* on another. Both are testing same external web site so receive same HTML code. Also use same versions of Geb, Webdriver and Firefox browser. Because I use *GebReportingSpec* it stores page on failure. I checked it in text editor and can see required element:

```
<div id="navContent">
    <ul>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="reports" title="Reports">Reports</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox driver has a peculiarity where it sometimes does not wait for the page to load before returning from a `WebDriver.get(String)` call. That's why Geb introduced [`atCheckWaiting` config option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-check-waiting). I would suggest setting it to a low value (I usually use 1 second) and your problem should go away.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's really strange but I cannot reproduce failing scenario after restarting server which runs tests. Will try your solution if problem appears again later.

Comment: Seems this problem still appears randomly so probably the only way to avoid it is to use yours suggested config option. Thanks!